# How can I force my app to use the inverse text direction for my Auto Layout constraints?

Tags: ios, macos, autolayout

I've designed my app to use Leading / Trailing constraints.

I do not have localizations for R2L languages but need to show an overlay on windows that might use that direction, and then I need to swap the direction of my controls to match those of the targeted app.

I can figure out which direction the other application uses.

What I can't figure out is an easy way to have my own window use the R2L text direction even though it wants to use L2R direction by default.

I could manually replace all my constraints at runtime, by using Left / Right instead of Leading / Trailing constraints, and then swap them out with the opposite constraints if required. But before I make that effort I like to know if there's an easier way by I can just tell the Auto Layout system to use the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`-userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622480-userinterfacelayoutdirection) (in Swift, `userInterfaceLayoutDirection(for:)`) to return the desired layout direction for your view.

Comment: And on macOS, where I need this, I can set the view's `userInterfaceLayoutDirection` as I just found out :)